# ContentResolver: can't query for existing calendars

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-calendar

I have a stange problem with this code:

```
private static final String[] CALENDARS_PROPS_PROJECTION = { Calendars._ID, Calendars.NAME, Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, Calendars.DELETED };

protected Uri getURI() {
     return CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI
            .buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,   "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
            .build();
}

ContentResolver cr = ...
Cursor cur = cr.query(getURI(), CALENDARS_PROPS_PROJECTION, Calendars.DELETED + "=?", new String[] { "0" }, null);
```

This code worked for a few month and I was able to enumerate all calendars that exist on my device, but *suddenly* it started to return a cursor which getCount() returns 0.

All calendars and events are visible via S Planner application as before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple: remove

```
.appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
.appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
```